# How can I access an actor (e.g. AcceptanceTester) in a Codeception helper

Tags: php, selenium, acceptance-testing, codeception

when I use the AcceptanceHelper generated by codeception (_support/AcceptanceHelper.php), how can I access the Actor / AcceptanceTester ($I). And how can I access my functions from StepObjects?

I have:

**acceptance/_steps/MyStepObject.php**

```
namespace AcceptanceTester;


class MyStepObject extends \AcceptanceTester
{
public function deleteCookies(){
    $I = $this;

    $I->amGoingTo("delete all cookies...");
    $I->executeInSelenium(function(\WebDriver $webdriver) {$webdriver->manage()->deleteAllCookies(); });
    $I->reloadPage();
}

public function loginUser($user,$password,$language = 'Untranslated')
{
    $I = $this; 

    $I->amOnPage(\LoginPage::$URL);
    $I->deleteCookies();
    $I->amGoingTo('fill the fields...');
    $I->fillField(\LoginPage::$usernameField, $user);
    $I->fillField(\LoginPage::$passwordField, $password);
    $I->click(\LoginPage::$loginButton);
}   
}
```

In the class `_support/AcceptanceHelper.php` I want to call methods from the AcceptanceTester like `$I->canSee('something')` and I want to call my own methods (like `'login'`) from my StepObject.

I know I can get a specific module (e.g. the WebDriver) with `$this->getModule('WebDriver')`. But how can I get the AcceptanceTester / my StepObject?

Answer (score 4):

Passing in the $I variable from the test. It's a bit verbose but works fine.

`public function deleteCookies($I){...}`

and then in tests write:

`$I->deleteCookies($I);`

Comment: OMG it's so simple! Why isn't this in the manual!?